# iOS simple socket communication

Tags: ios, sockets

I have socket server in Java and now I need simple TCP socket in my iOS app that will:

- Open socket connection
- Be able to send and recieve messages
- Close connection

So, only basic stuff... I need simplest solution possible.

I found few solutions, but none seem to work for me. If you could point me in right direction I will be very grateful. I need code with instructions.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you've tried, which solutions have you looked at? I think we'd all rather not repeat anything you may have already seen.

Comment: Pretty much everything in first 20 results you get on google when you type iphone socket... I'm just asking if anyone has working example that is understandible...

Comment: I assume you tried [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) then, right? What's in it "not working" for you?

Comment: What did you try? What issues did you have with them?

Comment: What is the smallest amount of code I need in Eclipse and in my app to make this work? I tried solution from tutorial, but it didn't help...

Comment: Using tutorial I am able to establish connection, bu can't send message to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
package jcolibri.examples.ABXRecommender;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileServer {
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
    // create socket
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
    while (true) {

        String str = "temp.png";
          File myFile = new File(str);
          String absolutePathOfFirstFile = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absolutePathOfFirstFile);   

      //File myFile = new File ("temp.png");
      //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

      System.out.println("Waiting...");
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

      // sendfile

      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];

      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      System.out.println("Sending...");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
      }
    }
}
```

This code is lightly adapted from somewhere. can't remember where though and it works for me. Your iOS code should know the IP address of your computer.

Hope that helps.